# Exposing kubernetes API to the outside world

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I was reviewing some material related to kubernetes security and I found it is possible to expose Kubernetes API server to be accessible from the outside world, My question is what would be the benefit from doing something vulnerable like this, Anyone knows business cases for example that let you did that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can use endpoints to deploy any service from your local. for sure you must implement security on your api.
I have created an application locally which builds using docker api, and deploy using kubernetes api.
Don't forget about securing your apis.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I can't find it worth the risk of exposing k8s API to just be able to deploy from local. Simply you can push you image to a registry and deploy it inside k8s. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: you can expose it only to you ;)